# Typo in elections page - space needed before "Nominations close"

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

I just found a typo in the Elections page: https://stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=primary

```
This election is currently in the nomination phase.Nominations close in 6 days 
                                                  ^^                         ^^
                                                  I need a space here!!      |
                                                                             |
                                             also a final dot here wouldn't hurt
```

Comment: They seem to be very strict about their spaces for some reason. Bandwidth maybe? :-D

Comment: Maybe they are code-golfing :)

Comment: @Oded what about the final dot?

Comment: It is on its way. Must have been a fat dot and is taking its time to cross the wires.

Comment: Haha it must be shy :) Thanks a lot, @Oded